# how to pass javascript array to php

Tags: php, javascript

I want to pass array myWorkout to 'play_workout.php'.
I want 'play_workout.php' to open and display the contents of myWorkout (for this example).
*(Once I see that this is working I will parse the data from myWorkout and write it back to a database).*
I'm not getting any errors in firebug, but play_workout is not being opened nor is is capturing the array object myWorkout.

I would appreciate a second glance at this.
Thanks as always!

**page workout_now.php**

```
<div id="playworkout"><button onClick="playWorkout()">Play Workout</button></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function playWorkout(){

  var arr = $("#dropTargetframe > li").map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('data-id');}).get();

     var myRoutine = arr;
     var myWorkout = new Array();
        for (var i in myRoutine){
           if (myRoutine[i])
             myWorkout.push(myRoutine[i]);
            }
          //array appears like ["4", "5", "1", "4"]
          JSON.stringify(myWorkout);
          encodeURIComponent(myWorkout);

         var url = "http://localhost/RealCardio/play_workout.php";

         $.get(url, myWorkout);
```

**page play_workout.php**

```
<?php
 ...
 $arrayWorkout = json_decode($_REQUEST['myWorkout']); 
 print_r($arrayWorkout);     
...
?>
```

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891320/how-to-pass-a-javascript-object-array-to-php-using-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that as in your comment the array elements doesn't contain any special chars, just numbers, simply do

```
var myWorkoutPost=myWorkout.join('x');
```

Transport this to the server the way you want (form hidden field, AJAX, ..) and in PHP do

```
$myWorkout=explode('x',$_REQUEST['myWorkoutPost']);
```

Comment: What would I populate in .join(x)? What value goes in 'x'?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo, should have been `'x'` , not `x` , I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both PHP and Javascript use JSON encoding so I would say the best way would be to JSON encode the array and then POST it as a hidden field to the PHP page and use JSON decode.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Encode this array to JSON, send it to php script and recieve it with $_POST.
Finally, decode JSON in php script.

Answer (score 0):

A work flow for almost every structured values 99% of the time it will do.

- Use `JSON.stringify([1,2,3])` it will give you a string `"[1,2,3]"`.
- Encode it with `encodeURIComponent("[1,2,3]")` you'll have something like this `"%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D"`
- Now it's save to be sent to PHP or any other server side language try to use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.google.jo/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=XMLHttpRequest&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest&ei=Xo5WT4ybGIjd8gOVg8D_CA&usg=AFQjCNFvKb4E0D_f5JyUt5ImQqSkJd-xMA&sig2=H8b_0hpxA-TaHw1dyAdCFg) or better [jQuery.get()](http://www.google.jo/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jQuery.get%28%29&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/&ei=dI5WT8jZDdOD8gOUr9jpCA&usg=AFQjCNG12g4HVp7TTpWDFytVbB9YP19ErQ&sig2=FWdNXBpZXlPDOIPbk0efpw) to send the values to PHP.

In php you'd do this:
 - `$arrayOfValues = json_decode($_REQUEST['name_of_parameter']);`
 - `print_r($arrayOfValues);`

Normally you'd need to include JSON library to support old browsers. More info on [JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: Is this how I would pass it in javascript -     $.get('play_workout.php',myWorkout,'','json');

Comment: I revised the question a little. Can you take another look?